# how do I embed a Manipulate expression into my personal website

Tags: code-review, code-request, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I have a number of `Manipulate[...]` codes that I like to embed to my personal website. But I face a problem. Here is a simple example of what I do (my `Manipulate` codes are much heavier than this.):

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[a*x]*a, {x, -10, 10}],{a, 1, 10}
          ] // EmbedCode[CloudDeploy[#, Permissions->{All->
               {"Read", "Interact"}}],ImageSize->{50, 80} + 
               ImageDimensions@Rasterize@#] &
```

This Code works as expected. However, when I use my `Manipulate` codes, after embedding it, `Starting Interface` message pups up and interface never starts. My questions are:

1. Is there a space limitation in free account `Cloud`? If so, how can I bypass it by using `Google Drive` or similar accounts to save my codes there and link `Google Drive` to the Cloud?
2. In several answers in this forum, there are few answers to the above question but I cannot understand it as it requires me to have  specialized programming skill. Here is the link to one of the answers available in the forum:

   (*The following Packlet is supposed to allow me to use Google Drive to save my Mathematica codes and run them in Google Drive*)

   ```
   PacletInstall[
      "ServiceConnection_GoogleDrive",
      "Site"-> "http://www.wolframcloud.com/objectsb3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
   ]
   ```

After installing this Paclet, I cannot use it. Can someone be so kind to write a step-by-step how-to-use guide for this Packlet work?

Thanks.

Comment: Embedding manipulates in sites has never really worked

Comment: @M.R.: Do you mean that there is no easy way to embed `Manipulate` to a website?

Comment: I would disagree a bit with @M.R. Embedding `Manipulate` has worked for me, but only when I have ensured that all of the data required for the `Manipulate` is explicitly included in the notebook. If the `Manipulate` needs to read a file on disk, it will not work.

Comment: Perhaps we need to  wait the Mathematica's version of  WebGL release.

Comment: @Shredderroy graphics/interaction are simply too slow in the cloud to be professional looking, anything that's too memory intensive flakes out, very simple things are possible tho

Comment: @cvgmt: What is `WebGL`?

Comment: @M.R.: I completely agree with your point because simple `Manipulate`s are working satisfactorily but large ones with large data retrievals from the Cloud simply fail. There is a video by @Vitaliy Kaurov showing how to embed `Codes` into Website but I cannot replicate it with my `Manipulate`. I hope Mathematica team comes up with a solution soon.